# android opengl view (with camera preview) is not visible after activity resumed

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity, camera, overlap

i overlapped opengl view and camera preview, and it shows everything at fresh start.

but after backed from child activity (after onResume()) opengl objects not appeared anymore.

i found some discussion about this weird problem, but i can't use following solution, because i should call child - map activity.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fe7c0755c2c05a5c

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859342/onresume-camera-reinit-black-screen is probably related.