# OnResume Camera Reinit Black Screen

Tags: android, xamarin.android, onresume, onpause, xamarin

I have a problem. After initializing the camera for a preview and bringing another app into focus, then back to my app: the preview shows up black. If I continue to take a picture, it takes a picture of where I point the camera normally.

Am I doing something wrong on the OnResume() override? Relative code is below:

```
public void ReleaseCamera()
    {
        if (myCamera != null)
        {
            myCamera.Release();
            myCamera = null;
        }
    }

protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();

        if (myButtonState == ButtonState.CameraActive)
            ReleaseCamera();
    }

protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        if (myButtonState == ButtonState.CameraActive)
            InitializeCamera();
    }

private void InitializeCamera()
    {
        SurfaceView mySurfaceView = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surfaceView1);

        myCamera = Android.Hardware.Camera.Open(cameraNumber);
        Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters p = myCamera.GetParameters();

        myCamera.SetDisplayOrientation(90); // Portrait
        myCamera.SetPreviewDisplay(mySurfaceView.Holder);
        myCamera.StartPreview();
    }
```

Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) gets called too early. You don't have the surface holder ready at this stage. You can try to introduce [`onPostResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostResume%28%29) handler in your Activity, and/or handle the [`SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html#surfaceChanged%28android.view.SurfaceHolder,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) event.

Comment: Thank you, using the SurfaceHolder Callback worked perfectly. :)